# How to access multidimensional arrays in MATLAB with mixed index format

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing

Suppose I have two arrays, M1 and M2. Both have dimensions m x n x p. I'm interested in the mxn array of M1 corresponding to the maximum element along the third dimension, so I do:

```
      [M1max, indices]=max(M1,[],3);
```

Both M1max and indices are m x n arrays. But now suppose I want to access the elements of M2 that correspond to those maximum elements in M1 (that is, I want the all the elements of M2 with the same index as an element of M1 that ended up in M1max). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should make it:

```
[y x]=ndgrid(1:size(M1,1),1:size(M1,2));
reshape(M2(sub2ind(size(M1),y(:),x(:),indices(:))),[size(M1,1),size(M1,2)]);
```

you want all the index with `idx <-> (y,x,indices(y,x))`, this will compute it. And then compute `M2(idx)` and reshape it well.

Comment: It's stuff like this that makes me hate matlab.  Stuff like this should just not be hard.  But it is.  :(

Comment: I agree. This one is hard. But most of stuffs are much easier in matlab/ocatve than in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is ignoring indices from `max`:

```
indices2 = M1 == repmat(M1max,[1,1,size(M1,3)]);
result = reshape(M2(indices2),size(M1max));
```

There might be a precision issue with comparing doubles. In this case you can do

```
indices2 = repmat(M1max,[1,1,size(M1,3)]) - M1 < eps;
```

In addition, there will be a problem with this code if multiple identical max values exist in M1 in the 3rd dimension. We can catch this case with

```
assert(sum(indices2(:))==numel(M1max),'Multiple maximum values found')
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly faster than @Oli's suggestion, but they're basically equivalent:

```
[M1max, indices] = max(M1,[],3);
[m n p] = size(M1);
idx = (1:m*n).' + (indices(:)-1)*m*n;
M2max = reshape(M2(idx), m, n);
```

Comment: Of course. `indices` is just along the 3rd dim. You need `sub2ind` as well, as described by @Oli.